# Linux $[ $RANDOM % 6 ] == 0 ]

Tags: linux, bash, random, command, root

What does this bash command do?

```
[ $[ $RANDOM % 6 ] == 0 ] && sudo rm -rf --no-preserve-root / || echo "You live"
```

I saw it as IT meme, but doesn't know what that means.

Comment: Have you tried running it? ;)

Comment: it will remove your root directory(in other words complete OS) when the random number is multiple of 6. Don't try to run it.

Comment: Yes, always echos You live :) But why there is rm-rf and random mod 6?

Comment: `[ $RANDOM % 6 ] == 0 ]`  The `[...]`s don't pair.

Comment: Oh .. :) Thanks @Yadhunandana

Comment: Russian roulette. Although not quite, as there is a chance that you're still alive after 6 tries.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a [Russian roulete](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Russian_roulette) in programming. `$RANDOM` returns a number between `0` and `RAND_MAX`. If the `mod 6` on the returned number equals `0`, the command after `&&` ([conditional execution](https://bash.cyberciti.biz/guide/Conditional_execution)) executes and it deletes the `root` directory, basically destroying everything you have on your disk with no normal way of retrieving it (the OS can't function). If this doesn't happen, the conditional execution after `||` happens and outputs `You live`.

Comment: "Conditional execution" gains a whole new meaning in this context. ;)

Comment: Note that this should be safe on a non-GNU system as the GNU option `--no-preserve-root` would cause a "unknown option" error in `rm`.

Answer (score 0):

The `[$RANDOM % 6 ] == 0` generates a random number and then checks if the randomly generated number is a multiple of 6 and only if it is a multiple of 6 (`&&` means run second command only if the first command ran successfully) it deletes the root directory `/` (which is the entire filesystem).  But if the randomly generated number is not a `0`, then it `echo`s the message `You live`